# SQL based Northwind, hard time on filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

So in a practice site there is a question:

> Which Product is the most popular? (number of items)

This means that There are Customers, and they want to know the most popular Ordered Product by the Customers(Overall Orders of TOP 1 ordered Product).

I Sincerely do not know How to solve this one.

Any help?

What I've tried so far is:

```
SELECT TOP(1) ProductID, ProductName
FROM Products
GROUP BY ProductID, ProductName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

But that's far from what they have asked.

 In this one, I just get the top 1 Product with the lowest count, but that doesn't mean anything about the customers who ordered this product.

That only means that this specific Item could have been at low quantity and still is lower then the others, while the others were very high quantity and now just low (but still not low enough)

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Is there an Orders table?

Comment: Yes. Indeed @Mihn Northwind is a familiar database of Microsoft for practicing purposes

Comment: Think about _popularity_. Most popular product can be a) that gave most sale amount, b) sold in greatest number, and c) sold to greatest number of unique customers. Old good `Northwind` keep all this information. You have to learn how to ask him.  _Hint_: Look at `Orders` and `Order Details` tables.

Answer (score 0):

If the data exists in that table, you might just need to order by something more sophisticated than count, like summing the quantity (if that column exists). Also, if ProductID and ProductName are already unique identifiers, note that you don't need the `group by` and `sum` at all.

`SELECT TOP(1) ProductID, ProductName
FROM Products
GROUP BY ProductID, ProductName
ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC`

I don't know what your keys are, but it sounds like you actually want to be counting how many times it was ordered by customers, so you may need to join on the Customers table. I am assuming here that you have a table Orders, that has one line per order and shares the ProductID key. I also assume that ProductID is unique in Products (which may not be true based on your first query).

`SELECT TOP(1) Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Orders 
ON Orders.ProductID = Products.ProductID
GROUP BY Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName
ORDER BY COUNT(Orders.OrderID) DESC`

This really depends on what tables and keys you have available to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 1 P.ProductID,P.ProductName,Sum(OD.Quantity)AS Quantity
 From [Order Details] OD
       inner join Products P ON P.ProductID = OD.ProductID
       Group By P.ProductID,P.ProductName
       Order by Quantity Desc
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You can workout something like this, (Table name/schema may differ)

```
with cte_product
as
(
select ProductID,Rank() over (order by Count(1) desc) as Rank from
Orders O
inner join Product P
on P.ProductID = O.ProductID
group by ProductID
)
select P.productID, P.ProductName from
cte_product ct
inner join product p
on ct.productId = p.ProductID
where ct.Rank = 1
```

Crux is usage of RANK() to get most popular product. Rest you may fetch columns as per need using relevant Joins.

Comment: Totally wrong answer. `Orders` table doesn't have productID field. `Northwind` is still available for download from Microsoft, and @Akanksha Singh should have done it first.

Comment: With due respect Sir @Alex, Thanks for the suggestion but I have full fledged databases of my company to work upon. And I don't find it a pre-requisite to memorize your favourite NORTHWIND for being a SQL developer. I agree that I no more have NORTHWIND which I had long back in my basic learning phase. Moreover, if you read my answer again,as the user N3wbie, like you, is also a big fan of Northwind, and didn't share the schema, that is why I mentioned that he can 'workout something like this' and suggested to go for RANK() and relevant joins.

Comment: Dear @Akanksha, the question came from a freshman who can hardly appreciate CTE and RANK functions. They should learn simple things first and don't blow their brains with very advanced things. With all respect...